# Hypothesis testing with faulty data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, asymptotics, mixture-distribution, information-theory

I would like to ask if there's any existed works about hypothesis testing with faulty data.

The specific question is as follows:
In normal hypothesis testing, say I have n i.i.d. datas $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ with distribution $P_0$ under $H_0$, and $P_1$ under $H_1$. Now a fraction $b$ of the datas are compromised, so they follows different distribution: $Q_0$ under $H_0$ and $Q_1$ under $H_1$, but I don't know witch $bn$ of the datas are compromised. Considering the asymptotic regime($n\to\infty$), my goal is to find the optimal error exponent(either Neyman-Pearson or Bayesian formulation) under this setting.

I'm trying to find some reference about this question or similar ones(for example, the compromised data are just some useless deterministic sequence), but failed to find one.
Any advise will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Mixture distributions might be one keyword to search for.

Comment: @Björn  Thanks, looks like that's what I'm looking for!